# Where is the image for the side menu stored?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Looking to change the size and maybe appearance to the tabbed button/image at the top left, which when clicked opens the side menu but I cant find where it is stored/sourced in the project. Does anyone know? Tried searching entire project for .png, tried looking in masterdetail, tried looking in MenuPage

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking after what called a **Navigation icon** or **flyout icon**.

On Android and on an Shell based app if you look at the calling [GetThemedContext()](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4048fab83b78c83786cb8dbbbd1380fa49b1a73f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/ContextExtensions.cs#L103) call in [ShellToolbarTracker.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4048fab83b78c83786cb8dbbbd1380fa49b1a73f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ShellToolbarTracker.cs#L395) seems getting the default native one (providing that `FlyoutIcon` is not set). Didn't see explicit mentioned on Android that the default icon is hamburger one but you can see in [ActionBar](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top#anatomy), which after that is assigned to  `toolbar.NavigationIcon` [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4048fab83b78c83786cb8dbbbd1380fa49b1a73f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ShellToolbarTracker.cs#L406-L418).

So, if you want to customize it under [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) you can use the [`Shell.FlyoutIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-icon) property by either specifying a font glyph icon or an image.

Comment: Hey Sorry for the late reply I'm only getting back to this issue now...Will be looking at it tomorrow and will leave feedback, thanks again so much for the help